# Conditionally add class to a parent class in scss

Tags: css, sass

I'm trying to add a css class to the parent (li-element) in scss when a class is present in child.

```
.main-menu {
  ul {
    li {
      &:has(> a.router-link-active) {
        border-left: 5px solid red;
        color: white;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The html looks like this:

```
<div class="main-menu">
  <ul class="list-unstyled">
    <li>
        <a href="/" class="router-link-exact-active router-link-active">lorem
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Unfortunately not

Comment: Actually your question should read "how to style a parent if it's child has a given class". You aren't adding a class to the parent, just changing it's style. Currently there is no way to do this without JavaScript.

Comment: Depending on how you are determining which element gets the `.router-link-active` class you could implement logic to attach a class (e.g. `.has-active-link`) to the `li` element and style it directly. This would be more inline with your current question, but yet is still not viable with pure CSS or a pre-processor.